# If $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic rings and $S$ has an extension, is there a natural extension of $R$ isomorphic to it?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic rings and $B$ is an extension of $S$, is there a natural way to construct an extension $A$ of $R$ such that there exists an isomorphism from $A$ to $B$ that preserves the isomorphism between $R$ and $S$?
I have often seen proofs that start with a ring such as $R$ and construct an extension $B$ to an isomorphic ring $S$ as above, merely identifying $R$ with $S$ to say that $R$ has a particular extension with the desired properties. I ignored this point as an embedding has always sufficed and I figured explicitly constructing an extension of $R$ would be trivial. However, my first attempt at actually constructing $A$ came down to verifying a surprising number of cases. Would this sort of naive "substitution" approach work and is there a more elegant way to do this?

My attempt:

Without loss of generality let $R$ and $B$ be disjoint and let $A$ have the underlying set $R\cup{B\backslash{S}}$. Let $\varphi$ be the isomorphism between $R$ and $S$ and define multiplication such that
$$\forall a,b\in A\qquad ab=
\begin{cases}
ab, &\text{if}\ a,b\in R\ \text{or}\ a,b\not\in R\ \text{and}\ ab\not\in S\\
\varphi^{-1}(ab), &\text{if}\ a,b\not\in R\ \text{and}\ ab\in S\\
\varphi(a)b, & \text{if}\ a\in R, b\not\in R\ \text{and}\ \varphi(a)b\not\in S\\
\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(a)b), &\text{if}\ a\in R, b\not\in R\ \text{and}\ \varphi(a)b\in S
\end{cases} $$
and extending the remaining cases symmetrically for $a,b$. Then we then define addition analogously and define the map $A$ to $B$ to be the identity on $A\backslash R$ and to be equal to $\varphi$ on R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead you let $\varphi:S\to R$ be an isomorphism, and define $\varphi:B\to A$ in the obvious way ($\varphi(b) = b$ if $b\in B\backslash S$), then the ring structure on $B$ induces a natural ring structure on $A$ that is precisely what you want (and what you have defined above).